# Migrate from an architecture to another

Tags: java, architecture, frameworks

I have an existing Java architecture that uses a basic proprietary framework.
I want to start developing new functionalities in a framework, ex Play.

In that way I will not lose existing functionalities, I will replace them slowly and I will probably end up seamlessly with a rewritten application.

Is this wise to do? Or there are other better ways to face this kind of transition from one framework to another?

Comment: what does "es Play" mean?

Comment: We do not know your application, your requirements, your old framework, and it is not clear which new framework you are talking of. So how do you expect to get a sensible answer for this question? Voting to close as "unclear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have an application using an old, rusty framework A, and you want to move towards framework B.

This is a type of refactoring that can happen due to a lot of reasons, most of which can be reduced to "we don't want framework A as a dependecy anymore". Reasons can be varied, such as A is not maintained anymore, B has nicer features and so on.

This definetly happens. However, the transition is hard and painful. The safest way to transition is to create separate branches, where you transition a piece of the application. Never mix transitioning with new development, since, if something goes wrong, is hard to trace.

But, in the end, think if it is worth it. Yes, B might be better, but is it good enough to be worth the cost of refactoring/revalidating the whole project?

Comment: The disadvantage with doing the transition in a separate branch is  the hellish merge afterwards when you're trying to integrate development that happened in the mean time. Switching between frameworks is a huge task any way you do it, but I've come to believe that the best (and in the long run cheapest) way to do any large-scale refactor is to halt all other development in the mean time.